# Visual studio 2022 Xamarin Remoted iOS simulator does not connect and shows black screen after VS update 17.1.3

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, ios-simulator, visual-studio-2022

I have a Xamarin.Forms project running on iOS simulators.
I recently updated Visual studio 2022 to 17.1.3.
After upgrade whenever I try to run the app on any iOS simulator, the simulator gets stuck at Blank screen like below. And it does not show anything on screen.

[image]

When I checked in the paired Mac that I use to build the project, there the iOS simulator window shows as blank too, and the title shows as iPhone xxx - External display.

If anyone has encountered this before and solved it, please help.

Comment: May I ask you what mac you are using and what version of Xcode and macOS? 

Comment: The Mac is M1 chip Macbook pro,  Mac OS 12.3.1, Xcode 13.3,

Comment: Thanks for your response.This is an known issue.Please refer to Trevor's answer.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes#known-issues-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very annoying, but Microsoft wrote in the [release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes#known-issues):

> Deploying an iOS app with Visual Studio on 2022 and Apple Xcode 13.3 results in a Remote iOS simulator window with a blank/black screen. Workaround: Disable the "Remote Simulator to Windows" check box in the iOS Settings under the Tools - Options menu. The iOS app should deploy correctly on the macOS host.

Looks like it's temporarily broken and they're working on it.

Answer (score 0):

This impacts Visual Studio 2019 and disabling the Remote Simulator to Windows solves the problem there too. Thanks.

Visual Studio 16.11.19
Xamarin.iOS 15.2.0.17
Xcode 13.3 on MacOS 12.6